# IBM Worklight 6.1 Hybrid App increace version

Tags: version, ibm-mobilefirst

We created a new Worklight project. It has a http adapter that point to IBM Domino server. It's works well with eclipse dev. server and through real Worklight server. When I increase the version on app, it's steal works with dev server, but not works through the real Worklight server.

Answer (score 0):

From reading the question, an obvious observation I must make here is have you make sure that you have deployed the updated .wlapp via the Worklight Console belonging to the "real server".

Comment: Yes, I deployed the wlapp and adapter, and also tried to replace the whole war file.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution for my own question. Create everything from scratch on server (remove and delete all wlapp) and clean the Eclipse project (project clean, delete remaining temp files) and rebuild-install solves the problem.